# C# Starting threads from a Loop throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: c#, multithreading

It's very weird because It's very apparent that the loop condition will never cause an Exception

```
Thread [] threads = new Thread[threadData.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < threadData.Length; i++)
{
   threads[i]= new System.Threading.Thread(() => threadWork(threadData[i]));
   threads[i].Start();
}
```

It just causes IndexOutOfBoundsException for threadData[i]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the normal problem of loop capturing - you've captured the loop variable, so by the time the thread actually starts, `i` is the final value, which is an invalid index into the array. The solution is to create a new variable *inside* the loop, and capture that instead:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadData.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < threadData.Length; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    threads[i]= new System.Threading.Thread(() => threadWork(threadData[copy]));
    threads[i].Start();
}
```

You can read more about this on Eric Lippert's blog: [part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx); [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx).

Personally I would consider using `List<T>` more though, and using `foreach` where possible - or even LINQ. `foreach` wouldn't have solved this problem, admittedly, but it would be generally cleaner IMO.

Here's an example of how you might have done it in LINQ:

```
List<Thread> threads = threadData.Select(x => new Thread(() => ThreadWork(x)))
                                 .ToList();
foreach (Thread thread in threads)
{
    thread.Start();
}
```

Or with a straight foreach loop, starting each thread as you go:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (var data in threadData)
{
    var dataCopy = data;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => ThreadWork(dataCopy));
    thread.Start();
    threads.Add(thread);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I marked the correct answer for the guy that replied first.

Comment: @deadlock: Actually you didn't... I replied marginally before chibacity did, but never mind :)

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I was mistaken. Correct answer goes for you Jon.

Comment: @Jon Damn you Skeet! Adding that extra detail was a waste of time. :)

Comment: @chibacity: Have a +1 from me instead :)

Comment: @Jon Cheers for the + 1 but the sad fact is that I had reached my daily rep cap before I answered the question, so I only received rep from getting the accepted answer! Oh, the irony :)

Answer (score 10):

You have captured over the loop variable `i` which may cause the last value of 'i' to be used when each thread eventually executes and retrieves data from `threadData`. Assign `i` to a variable in the loop and use that instead, e.g.:

```
Thread [] threads = new Thread[threadData.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < threadData.Length; i++)
{
    int index = i;
    threads[i]= new System.Threading.Thread(() => threadWork(threadData[index]));
    threads[i].Start();
}
```

Eric Lippert has a very nice article on the phenomenon here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/16/closing-over-the-loop-variable-part-two.aspx

For an insight into why this happens, consider that the threads will execute at some undetermined point in the future, perhaps after the loop has finished. `Start` signals that the thread should start, it actually starts asynchronously though i.e. not immediately. Given this, we can see that the lambda passed to the `Thread` may execute well past the loop finishing. So how can it have a reference to `i`?

In short the compiler will create a helper class that can encapsulate `i`, then replace references to `i` with this helper class. This allows the lambda to have a reference to `i` outside of the scope of the loop. A nice example of compiler magic, but in this case has a non-obvious side-effect i.e. it captures over the loop variable:

```
    private class LambdaHelper
    {
        public int VarI { get; set; }
    }

    private static void SomeMethod()
    {
        LambdaHelper helper = new LambdaHelper();

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadData.Length];

        for (helper.VarI = 0; helper.VarI < data.Length; helper.VarI++)
        {
          threads[helper.VarI] = new Thread(() => ThreadWork(data[helper.VarI]));
          threads[helper.VarI].Start();
        }
    }
```

Here we can see that `VarI` is used in place of `i`. The non-obvious side-effect is that when the threads execute they all see a shared value i.e. `VarI`. If the threads start after the loop has finished, they will all see the maximum value of `i`.

The fix is to assign `i` to a temporary variable inside the loop as detailed in the first code example.